# Closure of attributes definition clarification

Tags: database-theory, relational-theory

A databases book I am using states [1]:

> The closure of *{A1, A2, ..., An}* under the FD's in *S* is the set of attributes *B* such that every relation that satisfies all the FD's in set *S* also satisfies *A1 A2 ... An -> B*.

I'm not trying to nitpick, but shouldn't it say "...the set of ***all*** attributes *B*..." or am I reading it too strictly? The blockquote above seems to indicate any attribute functionally determined by *{A1, A2, ..., An}* is a closure, yet the algorithms given later in the text seems to define a closure as all attributes functionally determined.

[1] Ullman, Jeffrey D., and Jennifer Widom. A first course in database systems. 3rd ed. Upper Saddle River, NJ: Pearson/Prentice Hall, 2008.